# How long does it take it typically take for call value of changed variable to update?

Tags: web3.py, infura

I'm trying to mine a proof of work contract. Each time a solution is found, the return value for `units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()` should change.

I ran two instances of this script (with different PUBLIC_KEYs) to see what would happen if multiple people were trying to solve a problem for the same contract.

From what I see on [etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8c4d48b42cdff260f14bbad4e10d4144f1898bd4), it appears that sometimes the solutions found are not valid. The only feasible way I can see this being true is if `units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()` is not returning the current `challenge_number_hex`. What should I do to prevent this problem?

Here's my script for replication.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time

INFURA_ROPSTEN_URL = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<api>"

# metamask account information
PUBLIC_KEY = "0x3FaD9AccC3A39aDbd9887E82F94602cEA6c7F86f"
PRIVATE_KEY = "<private_key>"

UNITS_ADDRESS = "0x8C4D48B42cdff260F14BBaD4E10d4144F1898bD4"
# from truffle build. For ABI
JSON_PATH = "../truffle/build/contracts/Units.json"



import logging
extra = {'miner_public_key': PUBLIC_KEY}
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(miner_public_key)s : %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)

logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def set_up_web3():
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(INFURA_ROPSTEN_URL))
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = PUBLIC_KEY
    return web3

def get_units_contract_object():
    with open(JSON_PATH, 'r') as json_file:
        abi = json.load(json_file)['abi']
    return web3.eth.contract(address=UNITS_ADDRESS,abi=abi)

def solve(web3, units):
    nonce = np.random.randint(0,1e10)
    while True:
        challenge_number_hex = HexBytes(units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()).hex()
        my_digest_hex = web3.solidityKeccak(
                            ['bytes32','address','uint256'],
                            [challenge_number_hex, PUBLIC_KEY, nonce]).hex()
        my_digest_number = int(my_digest_hex,0)
        target = units.functions.getMiningTarget().call()
        if my_digest_number < target:
            return (nonce, my_digest_hex, int(challenge_number_hex,0))
        else:
            nonce += 1

def build_transaction(units, nonce, digest_hex, txn_count):
    return units.functions.mint(
                    nonce,
                    digest_hex
            ).buildTransaction({
                "nonce" : txn_count,
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    web3 = set_up_web3()

    txn_count = 11000 # web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY)
    units = get_units_contract_object()

    _cycle_goal = 20
    _prev_finish = time.time()
    _wait_time = 0
    while True:
        target = units.functions.getMiningTarget().call()
        nonce, digest_hex, challenge_number = solve(web3, units)

        mint_txn = build_transaction(units, nonce,digest_hex, txn_count)
        signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(mint_txn, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
        txn_address = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
        txn_count += 1

        log = f"Solution found! nonce={nonce}, digest_hex={digest_hex}, challenge_number={challenge_number}, txn_address={signed_txn}"
        logger.info(log)

        _finished = time.time()
        _elapsed = _finished - _prev_finish
        _additional_wait = _cycle_goal - _elapsed
        _wait_time += _additional_wait
        log = f"Waiting {_wait_time}"
        logger.info(log)
        _prev_finish = _finished
        time.sleep(_wait_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible explanation of your problem is that the value is correct when you started to solve the problem but it changed in the middle of your computations. You should check if the solution is valid before sending it.

It is hard to predict how much time it will take a transaction to be mined. It depends on external factors like network congestion and gas price.

For mining a common approach is to have the miner listen for events, like a new block created. If such event is fired then stop computation in the old block and restart with the new one.

Comment: shouldn't this line `challenge_number_hex = HexBytes(units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()).hex()` since its being ran with every attempt of a solution make that not a problem?

Comment: @financial_physician Ethereum is a distributed computer, computations are not synchronized. Perhaps you didn't get the newest block yet, or you are in a fork. Between the request for challenger number and the solution submission someone else might have modified it.

Comment: Okay, I mine the same way as [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31#events) (0xBTC) contract. But I don’t see any failed solutions there. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: @financial_physician It has some failures like [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f45e6ff3bec5eba4aff79f71ea8d174fadf35afa28196bea63a73f4eb175ee6). Since submissions are less frequent that in your contract it might favour less possibility of a conflict. You can verify a solution before sending the transaction.

Comment: how can I verify it? Usually ‘sendrawtrasaction’ throws an error if it doesn’t think it’ll process correctly. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @financial_physician You can check that challenge number hasn't changed. You can try if calling estimateGas uses less gas that correct transactions. Sendrawtransaction has some checks like correct nonce but it will not check if the transaction will revert.